# Can't pass value into re.findall (python)

Tags: python

Can anyone help me understand why this works...

```
z = re.findall(r'(foobar)', string)
```

But this doesn't?

```
regexStr = "r'(foobar)'"
z = re.findall(regexStr, string)
```

I've printed regexStr and determined that it's output is IDENTICAL to r'(foobar)'.

Can someone pls help?  I've also tried escaping the apostrophes too.

JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to your problem is

```
regexStr = r'(%s)' % searchString
```

where searchString will replace %s

In Python it is often better to use this construct than regular concatenation. (meaning str1 + str2 + ... )
Especially as you don't have to care about converting ints doubles and so on.

More on the subject here: [3.5. Formatting Strings](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html)

The r should not be part of the string, it only tells the python interpreter what kind of string it is:

```
r('hello\n')  # Raw string => (hello\n)
u'unicodestring'
```

Answer (score 3):

The "r" modifier on string should be outside of the quotes

```
regexStr = r'(foobar)'
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html) - "String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences."

Comment: Interesting.  I thought when you assign a string to a text variable, you have to include quotes around the string. Thanks Rich!

Comment: Actually, what I need to do is to pass the foobar value into this string, like this <regexStr = "r'(" + searchString + ")'">.  Since the solution you gave me doesn't include quotes around the whole string, how do I concatenate the string as illustrated above?

Comment: @jond _"The "r" modifier on string should be outside of the quotes

"_ So **"r'("** isn't right. Maybe you want to do : ``RegexPatternString = re.escape(searchString).join('()')``

Answer (score 0):

The `r` modifier builds a *raw* string. It tells Python not to convert backslash escape sequences to special characters, such as `\t` or `\n`, for built-in strings. It has nothing to do with regular expression escape sequences.

```
>>> len('\t')  # tab character only
1
>>> len(r'\t') # backslach character followed by a tee
2
```

However, regular expression syntax has its own set of escaping rules which often collide with the escape rules of built-in Python strings. The `r` keyword helps us only deal with one.  For example the first string below is a regular expression text that matches word characters, so is the second one because Python converts `\\` to `\` for built-in strings unless the `r` keyword is provided.

```
>>> re.compile(r'\w') == re.compile('\\w')
True
```

In your case `r'(foobar)'` is exactly equivalent to `'(foobar)'` because there is no backslash sequence to escape. This string is a regular expression *text* only in your mind. The `r` keyword does not tell Python to interpret the string that way. Python only knows about regular expression *objects* which you build with `re.compile()` or which are inherently compiled with methods like `re.findall()`.

Compiling regular expression objects have its own set of rules different from built-in string escape sequence rules and regex rules are not related to the `r` keyword. The regular expression compiler does not understand its special meaning, only the Python interpreter does.

In your case the `r` keyword in `"r'(foobar)'"` has no special treatment, because it is directly passed to the regex compiler. You are effectively building a regular expression that searches a string beginning with `"`, followed by `r` and so on. That's why two expressions differ.

```
>>> re.compile(r'(foobar)') == re.compile('"r(foobar)"') # your expressions
False
```

The usage of the `r` keyword has no effect here:

```
>>> re.compile(r'(foobar)') == re.compile('(foobar)')
True
>>> re.compile(r'"r(foobar)"') == re.compile('"r(foobar)"')
True
```

For more information:

- http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals
- http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax